# How to delete canvas on Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import font

def deleteButton(event):
    canvas.delete("tag1")

main = tkinter.Tk()
main.geometry("1280x720+320+180")
main.resizable(0,0)

cv = tkinter.Canvas(main, bg = "turquoise", width = 200, height = 200)
cv.create_polygon(400, 400, 400, 400, fill = "turquoise", tag = "tag1")
cv.place(x = 300, y = 300)
cv.pack()

start_button = tkinter.Button(main, text = "Play!", command = deleteButton, fg =` `"white", bg = "#0A9AFF", relief = "flat")
start_button.place(x = 625, y = 300)

main.mainloop()
```

when run this code, I get

> "TypeError: deleteButton() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'event'."

I've already tried to `.bind` but I couldn't fix it.
I want to delete canvas with pushing button, how can I do that?

Starting new line doesn't work.
Thank you

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the canvas widget, or delete the things that have been drawn on the canvas? Have you read any documentation or searched for the error "missing 1 required positional argument event'? You'll get lots of hits on this site.

Comment: I want to remove the part `cv.create_polygon(400, 400, 400, 400, fill = "turquoise", tag = "tag1")`; I thought that deleteButton needs "event" and then I tried `start_button.bind("<Button-1>", deleteButton), and I got "NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined"

Comment: You've named your canvas `cv`, not `canvas`.

Comment: Thanks; the error was fixed, but `cv.delete("tag1")` doesn't work, cv seems not to be cleaned; what is with wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To clear a canvas, use the delete method. Give it the special parameter "all" to delete all items on the canvas (the string "all"" is a special tag that represents all items on the canvas):

canvas.delete("all")

If you want to delete certain items on the canvas (such as foreground objects, while leaving the background objects on the display) you can assign tags to each item. Then, instead of "all", you could supply the name of a tag.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
I tried `canvas.delete("all")` and adding `tag = "tag1"` but it seemed not to work; I might not understand events on tkinter

Answer (score 0):

When you use `bind`, it automatically passes a parameter that represents the event. Therefore, a function needs to accept this parameter. When you use `command=`, there is no event parameter, therefore your function shouldn't accept one.

As for the error `"NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined"`, that's because you've named your canvas `cv`, not `canvas`. To delete the items on your specific canvas it would be `cv.delete(...)`, not `canvas.delete(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
I changed `canvas` to `cv`, and then the bug was fixed but the function is not working now. When I use `command = deleteButton` and then I get `TypeError: deleteButton() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`. What should I set for deleteButton()?